# In A Classic ASP Environment: Protecting the full URL against XSS

Tags: asp-classic

I am wondering if there is a way to create a whitelist or blacklist function that accepts an entire url and goes to 404 if an invalid character is found.

Thanks for your insights.

Comment: Do you just want a function that accepts a URL as a parameter then compares it to a list and returns True if the URL exists in the list?

Comment: Could try the InStr function

Comment: What version of IIS are you running?

Comment: We are running IIS 7.5.

Answer (score 0):

Consider installing [URLScan 3](http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/urlscan) to quickly protect your application from sql injection attempts and XSS attempts, as well as working through your application to properly sanitize your sql statements. It has various preset rules but also allows you to create your own custom whitelist (allow) or blacklist (deny) rules.

It also scans the urls at ISAPI level so you don't need to program anything into your application.

It allows redirect to a specific page with the `RejectResponseUrl` property